# jquery .animate with timefunction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, time, jquery-animate

he guys...

i use this litte code-snippet for jquery:

```
function updown() {
    $('#red').animate({top:'+=100'}, 5000, function() {
        $('#red').animate({top:'-=100'},5000, function(){
            updown();
        });
    });
}

updown();
```

(for movement to the right i use spritely)

and get this result:

[image: result]

but i want it like this:

[image: wish]

is there a way to realize that?

regards,
bernte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use jQuery `delay()` or Javascript's `setTimeout`, here's the former:

```
function updown() {
    $('#red').delay(7000).animate({top:'+=100'}, 5000, function() {
        $('#red').delay(3000).animate({top:'-=100'},5000, function(){
            updown();
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function updown() {
    $('#red').delay(3000).animate({top:'+=100'}, 5000, function() {
        $('#red').delay(7000).animate({top:'-=100'},5000, updown});
    });
}

updown();
```

Delay is what you want. Call, as the example above, parsing the time you want to wait before exec the next animation request. Beware to it, delay only works with animations. If you do, for example:

```
$("#red").delay(1000).css("display", "none");
```

The .css() will be called immediately, and not after 1000 ms.